# How to write loop in excel (XLS) robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I try to write value to excel file (XLS) with script below.
There are 4 rows value but output just display only 1 row.

Second question: Can I use existing file?

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections
Library           WriteExcel.Excel

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Write Excel Test
    [Tags]
    @{content}    Create List
    Append To List    ${content}    1    1    Test Case 1
    Append To List    ${content}    2    1    Test Case 2
    Append To List    ${content}    3    1    Test Case 3
    Append To List    ${content}    4    1    Test Case 4
    Write To Excel File    test3.xls    ${content}
```

This is my WriteExcel.py

```
import xlwt

class Excel(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "write to excel file"

    def group(self,lst, n):

         return zip(*[lst[i:n] for i in range(n)])
    def write_to_excel_file(self,filename,content_list):

            # Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
            workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
            worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('wb')

            #content_lists=[1,1,'hello',2,1,'brother',3,1,'how are you',4,1,'are you good today']
            t=self.group(content_list,3)
            #print(t)
            for item in t:
                worksheet.write(int(item[0]), int(item[1]), item[2])


            # close work book
                workbook.save(filename)
```

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzPkw.png)

Comment: your `t` contains exactly one tuple to be iterated/written into file:
`>>> mylist = [1, 1, "Test 1", 2, 1, "Test 2", 3, 1, "Test 3", 4, 1, "Test 4"]`
`>>> zip(*[mylist[i:3] for i in range (3)])`
`[(1, 1, 'Test 1')]`
So you need to iterate `group` by `n` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change to group function is required

```
def group(self,lst, size):
    return ([lst[i:i+size] for i  in range(0, len(lst), size)])
```

Yes it is possible to add data to existing file. Refer the below example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25144775/6626530 - thanks to @Chopra

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
def saveWorkSpace(fields):
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook('accounts.xls',formatting_info=True)
    r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
    r = r_sheet.nrows
    wb = copy(rb) 
    sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 
    sheet.write(r,0,fields['name'])
    sheet.write(r,1,fields['phone'])
    sheet.write(r,2,fields['email'])
    wb.save('accounts.xls')
    print 'Wrote accounts.xls'
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

I am going to try add data to existing file